# Merge objects with same key in array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I have an array of object as shown below.If the array has objects with same key values, then the resulting array should contain combination of both objects in ES5 version

```
var arr = [
{
    "abc": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "addr": "123",
       }
    ]
},
{
    "def": [
        {
            "first_name": "test",
            "last_name": "test"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "def": [
        {
            "first_name": "test1",
            "last_name": "test1"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

the expected output should be

```
var arr =[
{
    "abc": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "addr": "123",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "def": [
        {
            "first_name": "test",
            "last_name": "test"
        },
        {
            "first_name": "test1",
            "last_name": "test1"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Could anyone help me on this can be achieved? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Could you please reopen this question as the answers suggested were in ES6 version and I am looking for ES5 version as my application currently supports only ES5 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arr = [
{
    "abc": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "addr": "123",
       }
    ]
},
{
    "def": [
        {
            "first_name": "test",
            "last_name": "test"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "def": [
        {
            "first_name": "test1",
            "last_name": "test1"
        }
    ]
}]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {        
    const key = Object.keys(curr)[0]
    const found = acc.find(i => i[key])
    if (!found) {
        acc.push(curr)
    } else {
        found[key] = [ ...found[key], ...curr[key] ]
    }
    return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Code below should give the desired result.

## ES6

```
arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {        
    const key = Object.keys(curr)[0]
    const found = acc.find(i => i[key])
    if (!found) {
        acc.push(curr)
    } else {
        found[key] = [ ...found[key], ...curr[key] ]
    }
    return acc;
}, [])
```

## ES5

```
arr.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
  var key = Object.keys(curr)[0];
  var found = acc.find(function (i) {
    return i[key];
  });

  if (!found) {
    acc.push(curr);
  } else {
    found[key] = [].concat(found[key], curr[key]);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

using `filter` instead of `find`

```
arr.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
  var key = Object.keys(curr)[0];
  var found = acc.filter(function (i) {
    return i[key];
  })[0];

  if (!found) {
    acc.push(curr);
  } else {
    found[key] = [].concat(found[key], curr[key]);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: My application doesn't support ES6 version functions. Could you please translate it in ES5

Comment: Checkout the answer above.

Comment: For ES5 version got an error as 'Cannot find function find in object .' Any help?

Comment: `find` is ES5, it is not supported in IE so you can use `filter`, filter will return an array and use the index 0. if your `array` is null or undefined then you cannot run this function.
Replace the `find` with `filter` as shown below
`var found = acc.filter(function (i) {
    return i[key];
  })[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Using `object` and `array`

```js
var arr = [{
    "abc": [{
      "name": "test",
      "addr": "123",
    }]
  },
  {
    "def": [{
      "first_name": "test",
      "last_name": "test"
    }]
  },
  {
    "def": [{
      "first_name": "test1",
      "last_name": "test1"
    }]
  }
]

var b = {}

arr.forEach(c => {
  var key = Object.keys(c)[0]
  var value = Object.values(c)[0]
  if (!b[key]) b[key] = []
  b[key].push(...value)
})

// b is resultant object

var c = []
Object.keys(b).forEach(v => {
  let a = {};
  a[v] = b[v];
  c.push(a)
})

// c is converting object to array

console.log(c)
```

Comment: My application doesn't support ES6 version functions. Could you please translate it in ES5?